NestJs project dont resolve alias paths when start jest

When I launch the project "npm run start:dev" everything works well, but when I run the "npm run test" or "npm run test:e2e", I get this error:

FAIL  src/teacher/teacher.service.spec.ts   
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:

    Could not locate module @user/user.service mapped as:
    D:\Diplom_backend\nestjs-project\src\user.

    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/@user/": "D:\Diplom_backend\nestjs-project\src\user"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

      1 | import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
      2 | import { PrismaService } from '@prisma/prisma.service';
    > 3 | import { UserService } from '@user/user.service';
        | ^
      4 | import { CreditService } from 'src/credit/credit.service';
      5 | import { LessonService } from 'src/lesson/lesson.service';
      6 | import { MarkService } from 'src/mark/mark.service';

      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:759:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/teacher/teacher.service.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/teacher/teacher.service.spec.ts:2:1)

 FAIL  src/teacher/teacher.controller.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:

    Could not locate module @common/decorators mapped as:
    D:\Diplom_backend\nestjs-project\libs\common\src.

    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/@common/": "D:\Diplom_backend\nestjs-project\libs\common\src"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

      1 | import { JwtPayload } from '@auth/interfaces';
    > 2 | import { CurrentUser, Public } from '@common/decorators';
        | ^
      3 | import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
      4 | import { TeacherService } from './teacher.service';
      5 | import { ApiBearerAuth, ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';

      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:759:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/teacher/teacher.controller.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/teacher/teacher.controller.spec.ts:2:1)

Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total









my package.json:

"jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "json",
            "ts"
        ],
        "rootDir": ".",
        "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "**/*.(t|j)s"
        ],
        "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "roots": [
            "<rootDir>/src/",
            "<rootDir>/libs/"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "@prisma": "<rootDir>/src/prisma",
            "@prisma/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/prisma/$1",
            "@user": "<rootDir>/src/user",
            "@user/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/user/$1",
            "@common": "<rootDir>/libs/common/src",
            "@common/(.*)": "<rootDir>/libs/common/src/$1",
            "@auth": "<rootDir>/src/auth",
            "@auth/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/auth/$1"
        }
    }


my tsconfig.json:

"baseUrl": "./",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@prisma": ["src/prisma"],
            "@prisma/*": ["src/prisma/*"],
            "@user": ["src/user"],
            "@user/*": ["src/user/*"],
            "@common": ["libs/common/src"],
            "@common/*": ["libs/common/src/*"],
            "@auth": ["src/auth"],
            "@auth/*": ["src/auth/*"]
        }

and jest-e2e.json:

{
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "@prisma": "<rootDir>/../src/prisma",
        "@prisma/(.*)": "<rootDir>/../src/prisma/$1",
        "@user": "<rootDir>/../src/user",
        "@user/(.*)": "<rootDir>/../src/user/$1",
        "@common": "<rootDir>/../libs/common/src",
        "@common/(.*)": "<rootDir>/../libs/common/src/$1",
        "@auth": "<rootDir>/../src/auth",
        "@auth/(.*)": "<rootDir>/../src/auth/$1"
    }
}


I tried edit moduleNameMapper in package.json roots, but nothing worked.



sorry for my code format this my first question

Share the spec file in the question.
